# Jquery autocomplete runs after second key pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to make autocomplete work on each textboxes using with an attribute "kolonadi"

When i press a key in textbox, the page alerts me "keydown enterance" but the autocomplete is not running. If I press one key more it works correctly.

How can i modify this code?

This is my dynamic input:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$qtxt_UNVAN" type="text" id="MainContent_qtxt_UNVAN" class="textEntry2 ui-autocomplete-input" kolonadi="UNVAN" style="width:200px;" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

This is jquery autocomplete:

```
$('.textEntry2').keydown(function () {
   alert("keydown enterance"); 
  var kolonadi_ = $(this).attr("kolonadi");

    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/AutoCom.asmx/GetValues") %>',
                data: "{ 'word': '" + request.term + "','KullaniciIndexInGlob':'<%=KullaniciIndexInGlob %>','BaslikId':'<% =BaslikId %>','columnName':'" + kolonadi_ + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: The documentation for this widget are [here](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete). None of them suggest applying the widget on keydown. I would visit that page and look at the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make autocomplate each textboxes using textbox attr "kolonadi"

Then you need to make [a jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) that matches that attribute:

```
$('input[type="text"][kolonadi!=""]').each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

> ...when I press a key in textbox, page alert me "keydown enterance" but autocomp not running. If I press one key more it runs!

The problem is that [the jQuery UI `.autocomplete` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) doesn't immediately bring down the drop-down like you think it does.  If you call it once, it converts the input field permanently into an auto-completing field.

So what your code does is check for a keypress, and if it finds it, it turns the text field into an autocomplete.  Then the second time you enter a keypress, the auto-complete handler runs *and* your handler runs, and it gets converted into an autocomplete *again*.

So just call `.autocomplete` directly on page load, get rid of the `keydown` handler, and call it done.  You don't need your own key-down handler because the `.autocomplete` method will insert its own key-down handler.

Something like this:

```
var textEntry2 = $('.textEntry2');
var kolonadi_ = textEntry2.attr("kolonadi");

textEntry2.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/AutoCom.asmx/GetValues") %>',
            data: "{ 'word': '" + request.term + "','KullaniciIndexInGlob':'<%=KullaniciIndexInGlob %>','BaslikId':'<% =BaslikId %>','columnName':'" + kolonadi_ + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.split('-')[0],
                        val: item.split('-')[1]
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(e, i) {
        $("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** the previous code doesn't work, it's necessary to iterate in all inputs from class `textEntry2`.

You must call the autocomplete in `$(document).ready` function, not in each keydown. Assuming that all inputs in which you want to use autocomplete are from class `textEntry2`, you'll need something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.textEntry2').each(function() {
        var kolonadi_ = $(this).attr("kolonadi");
        $(this).autocomplete(/* do all stuff here */);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This only answers half the question, or I'd have given an upvote already.  The other half this answer missed is `I want to make autocomplete work on each textboxes using with an attribute "kolonadi"`